# How to upload image and show preview in text editor using react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i'm having a problem using draft-js text editor in react. My intention is to create a text editor where I can get the text to create a post, but I also need to get the image that you uploaded to the editor to place it as the cover of the post.

The following happens every time I load an image, it makes the request to the server. What I need is that the request is made once the user has submitted at the end of the creation of the post. So in this way I should not store images that the user regretted and then select another image.

frontend code:

```
export function EditorPost(props:any):JSX.Element{
  let {postcontent, setpostcontent} = props;
const [content, setContent] = useState(EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
  convertFromHTML("<h2>hola nena</h2>")
)));
const onEditorStateChange = (editorState:any) => {
  setContent(editorState); //UPDATE EDITOR STATE AND VALUE
  setpostcontent({
    ...postcontent,
    body:draftToHtml(convertToRaw(content.getCurrentContent())) //GET ONLY CONTENT OF THE FORM
  });
  console.log(postcontent);
  }
function uploadImageCallBack(file:any):Promise<any> {
  return new Promise(
   async (resolve, reject) => {
      const formdata = new FormData() 
      formdata.append('image', file)
     try{
     let resp = await axiosIntance.post('/upload', formdata);
      resolve(resp)
     }catch(err){
      reject(err);
     }
    }
  );
}

return (
  <>
<Editor
        editorState={content}
        onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}    
        toolbar={{
          inline: { inDropdown: true },
          list: { inDropdown: true },
          textAlign: { inDropdown: true },
          link: { inDropdown: true },
          history: { inDropdown: true },
          image: { uploadCallback: uploadImageCallBack, alt: { present: true, mandatory: true } },
        }}
      />
      </>
)


}
```

on the server i am using node and mysql. and create a model in the database for the posts, which contains the following columns: title, image (obtained from the text editor), body (html obtained from the text editor)